# Sendmessage from subclassed control (CEDIT) to parent window

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, sendmessage, cedit

I have subclassed a `CEdit` control (`CCheckeEdit`).

I need to catch `ON_CHANGE` for this class and send the message to dialog (catch `EN_CHANGE` in dialog, too).

In subclassed `CCheckeEdit`, I have followed hook procedure:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCheckedEdit, CEdit)
    ON_WM_CHAR()
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT()
    ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(EN_CHANGE, &CCheckedEdit::OnEnChange)
    ON_WM_TIMER()
    ON_WM_NCMOUSEMOVE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
//....
//....

void CCheckedEdit::OnEnChange()
{
    Validing();
    int res = ::SendMessage(GetParent()->m_hWnd, WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM)MAKELONG(3, EN_CHANGE), (LPARAM)GetParent()->m_hWnd);
}
```

and in the dialog I have:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CProjMfcDlg, CMjAcDialog)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDIT, &CProjMfcDlg::OnEnChangeEdit)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CProjMfcDlg::OnEnChangeEdit()
{
    CString str;
    GetDlgItemText(str);
    if(str==....)
    // some validating code
    // set some button disable or enable
}
```

But `CProjMfcDlg::OnEnChangeEdit()` will not process (I have breakpoint there).

What am I doing wrong?

`OnEnChange` procedure is whole in question above. Yes, I use a MFC reflection:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCheckedEdit, CEdit)
    ON_WM_CHAR()
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT()
    ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(EN_CHANGE, &CCheckedEdit::OnEnChange)
    ON_WM_TIMER()
    ON_WM_NCMOUSEMOVE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: The [`EN_CHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change) notification is sent to the parent of the control. Are you using [message reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/handling-reflected-messages)?

Comment: Tell us more about the `OnEnChange` "hook procedure".

Comment: I agree with IInspectable. `EN_CHANGE` is sent to the Edit's parent window to begin with, and is then being reflected to the Edit for processing. So, simply don't do the reflection. Or, if you must let the Edit process the reflected message, then you should send a *custom* message back to the parent window, don't reuse `EN_CHANGE` (which is likely to just confuse the parent).  Otherwise, just have the parent process `WM_NOTIFY` *before* reflecting `EN_CHANGE` to the Edit.

Answer (score 2):

I have just solved it.

The correct way is to use `ON_CONTROL_REFLEX_EX` instead `ON_CONTROL_REFLEX`.

Then the message is sent first to the control and then, depending of return value from control hook procedure (FALSE), also to the parent window.